# Sent email when when specific Value Occurs in a Row or the entire Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all, yes I'm a newbie :)

I would like to send an email when an specific value occurs in a row or much better if this check could be in entire sheet... both solutions will be helpfull for me to understand what I'm doing :)

I know that after creating this function I need to use the trigger feature

Very best regards and thanks in advance for you help.

Seb

This is my script resulting for bits of codes find on the web...

```
function CheckError() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('HistoMeteo'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('B:B'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('HistoMeteo'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in B:B; If true copy the same row to data array
  for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if ( testvalue[i] == '#N/A') {
    // Fetch the email address in B2
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HistoMeteo').getRange('B2');
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
    //var DailyTempsRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HistoMeteo').getRange('B13'); 
    //var DailyTemps = DailyTempsRange.getValue();
  // Send Alert Email
    var subject = 'Hoho Error in your page';
    var message = 'N/A message in your page check it asap';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome. Would you please explain- what is the problem with the script in your question.

Comment: Hi, this message is display "Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String) do not match the signature of the "MailApp.sendEmail" method. (line 36, file "Code")"

Comment: [Edit] the error into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The parameters (number[],String,String) do not match the signature of the "MailApp.sendEmail" method

- The method `MailApp.sendEmail` excepts three parameters - all of them strings:
  `(String,String,String)`
- the first parameter - the emailAddress has been recognized in your case as an array of numbers
- Why? because you pass it the return values of `emailRange.getValues();`
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns you **a two-dimensional array of values** - even if you apply it to a single cell
- Solution: Replace `getValues()` through [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

Comment: Ho great, It works ! thanks a lot for your precious help.